# Zsh prompt only renders correctly once

Tags: zsh, prompt

I recently changed my Zsh prompt to match a theme I like from oh-my-zsh (I'm ditching oh-my-zsh for compatibility reasons).

The prompt is:

```
PROMPT='%(?,%{$fg[green]%},%{$fg[red]%}) %% '
RPS1='%{$fg[blue]%}%~%{$reset_color%} '
```

I had multiple tmux panes open when I made this change to my `~/.zshrc` file. When I exited vim and entered `source ~/.zshrc` zsh rendered the prompt correctly. When I tried switching panes, and entering `source ~/.zshrc` it rendered incorrectly, and it has rendered incorrectly on all subsequent panes and windows created.

In the photo, the first pane I sourced ~/.zshrc in is on the left.

[image: First pane | Second pane]

Comment: What do you mean by “first tmux pane I sourced ~/.zshrc in”? Do you run `zsh` in both panes? If so `.zshrc` would have been sourced when you start zsh. Please post a way to reproduce this (including how to start tmux and create the panes), including all relevant tmux and zsh configuration files.

Comment: What it looks like is that the zsh configuration is different in the two panes, the one on the left has the `prompt_subst` option set and the one on the right doesn't.

Comment: Edited for more detail, adding `export PROMPT_SUBST` did the trick. Would you like to submit an answer so I can mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You evidently have different zsh configurations in the two panes. Make sure that the [`prompt_subst`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-PROMPT_005fSUBST) option is set. It seems that you set it in the left pane but it isn't present in your configuration. Add the following line to your `.zshrc`:

```
shopt -s prompt_subst
```

Note that if you use a framework such as oh-my-zsh, changing the value of this option may mess up its prompt setting framework. I don't use zsh configuration frameworks so you're on your own with that.

Comment: Of course, if one is going to use `%` sequences *anyway* one might as well use `%F{red}` and its ilk, get rid of `$fg` and `$reset_color`, and not have to worry about `prompt_subst` in the first place.